# Moving the multiple marker using latitude and longitude from server

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, tracking

Single marker is moving perfectly but when adding more than one marker it is not working fine.

```
  StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, Url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.e("GET_ASSIGNED_PROJECT", response);
            try {
                progressDialog.dismiss_dialog();
                JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject(response);
                message = jsonObject1.getString("message");
                if (message.equals("success")) {
                    startTimer();
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject1.getJSONArray("responseMessg");
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        ManagementHomeModel homePageModel = new ManagementHomeModel();
                        homePageModel.setRegistrationid(jsonObject.getString("Registrationid"));
                        homePageModel.setName(jsonObject.getString("Name"));
                        homePageModel.setImageUrl(jsonObject.getString("ImageUrl"));
                        homePageModel.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.getString("Latitude")));
                        homePageModel.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.getString("Longitude")));
                        double weblat = jsonObject.getDouble("Latitude");
                        double weblong = jsonObject.getDouble("Longitude");

                        latLng = new LatLng(weblat, weblong);

                        Glide.with(getContext()).load(ServiceUrl.IMAGE_OPEN_URL + jsonObject.getString("ImageUrl")).asBitmap().fitCenter().into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResourceReady(Bitmap bitmap, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                                webmarker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(weblat, weblong)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(getMarkerBitmapFromView(mCustomMarkerView, bitmap)));
                                cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10);
                                mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
                                finalmarker = mMap.addMarker(webmarker);
                                allManagementHomeModels.add(homePageModel);
                                allHashmarker.put(finalmarker, homePageModel);
                            }
                        });
                    }

                } else {

                    JSONObject object = jsonObject1.getJSONObject("responseMessg");
                    String responceresult = object.getString("ResposeResult");
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), responceresult, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("error", error.getMessage());
            progressDialog.dismiss_dialog();
        }
    });
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(20000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);




    final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    final Interpolator interpolator = new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator();
    final float durationInMs = 3000;
    final boolean hideMarker = false;
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        long elapsed;
        float t;
        float v;

        @Override
        public void run() {


            moveMarker = (new ArrayList<Marker>(allHashmarker.keySet())).get(pos);

            ManagementHomeModel model = (new ArrayList<ManagementHomeModel>(allHashmarker.values())).get(pos);
            startPosition = moveMarker.getPosition();

            elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
            t = elapsed / durationInMs;
            v = interpolator.getInterpolation(t);

            LatLng currentPosition = new LatLng(
                    startPosition.latitude * (1 - t) + (finalPosition.getLatitude()) * t,
                    startPosition.longitude * (1 - t) + (finalPosition.getLongitude()) * t);
            moveMarker.setPosition(currentPosition);


            if (t < 1) {
                // Post again 16ms later.
                handler.postDelayed(this, 16);

            } else {
                if (hideMarker) {
                    finalmarker.setVisible(false);
                } else {
                    finalmarker.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

not able to track all the marker at the same time. I need to track all the markers at the same time like ola cab. Only single marker can be able to track, not more than one. Kindly help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Add all markers in a list when adding a marker in google map. Then whenever you need to update the position of a marker just find the current marker from the list and update position.

Comment: I'm hiting the server every 3 seconds, to get the latest lat long code. can you tell the the flow when to call server and when to update?

Comment: You should use a socket connection channel for the real-time update of a marker. You can also use MQTT channel with the server for this type of real-time maker update. Otherwise, if you don't want these changes from the server side then you can update markers on success response.